# Html.Hidden() asp mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Im following the book ASP.NET MVC 2 by Steven Sanderson, and I don't understand the method helper Html.Hidden(), I mean, I don't know what does suppose to do.
this is the specific call:

Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)

Answer (score 0):

It basically hides a value from user (visitor of page), but keeps it available when you do POST with your model afaik.

Comment: First one is name of generated hidden input, second on is going to be its value. In this case, its a url. You can see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003040/asp-net-mvc-html-beginform-problem)